# How to include/exclude field in json(Jackson - conversion from Object to Json) while converting on the basis of some property in spring framework?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

Let class be

```
public class Student{
     (Annotate such that this field is included only for version 1 and excluded for others while serializing into json)
     private int id;
     private String name;
}
```

Is there any method in spring to achieve this?

Comment: what context? web, context loading of general serialization?

Comment: Web context. Actually while serving from controller which produces json format response.

Comment: @MichaelWiles it is regarding web context as specified in above comment